# Get <svg> element created by venn.js, when it is inside existing <svg> element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, venn.js

I have existing `<svg>` and want to include venn diagram into this element. Here is structure of my elements:

```
<svg id="main-svg">
  ... some elements, for example <g> or <svg> ...
  <svg> // this is Venn.js root element
    <g class="venn-area venn-circle" data-venn-sets="0">...</g>
    ...
  </svg>
</svg>
```

How can I get `<svg>` element, which was created by venn library?

---

Full code:

```js
const sets = [
  { sets: ['A'], size: 12 },
  { sets: ['B'], size: 12 },
  { sets: ['A', 'B'], size: 2 },
];

const chart = venn.VennDiagram();
d3.select('#main-svg').datum(sets).call(chart);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/benfred/venn.js/master/venn.js"></script>

<svg width="800" height="800" id="main-svg"></svg>
```

And I want to get this `<svg>` element:

> [image]

<sub>Thanks to library author for answer in [this issue](https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/issues/123#issuecomment-380261326)</sub>

Comment: `d3.select("#venn>svg")` or `d3.select("#venn").select("svg")`.

Comment: After your edit `d3.select("#main-svg>svg")`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should on your own create child `<svg>` element, which venn.js would use:

```
<svg id="main-svg">
  <svg id="inner_svg_which_would_be_used_by_venn"></svg>
</div>
```

Live demo:

```js
const sets = [
  { sets: ['A'], size: 12 },
  { sets: ['B'], size: 12 },
  { sets: ['A', 'B'], size: 2 },
];

const chart = venn.VennDiagram();
d3.select('#main-svg').datum(sets).call(chart);
const rootSvg = d3.select('#inner_svg_which_would_be_used_by_venn');
// use rootSvg somehow
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/benfred/venn.js/master/venn.js"></script>

<svg id="main-svg" height="800" width="600">
  <svg id="inner_svg_which_would_be_used_by_venn"></svg>
</svg>
```

[Live demo on bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/dima74/ce625fd42e39672fd9e044f4c4a65ec3/e08ada8d75fe0b5bbd368ac980db1054ab04b2ab)